# Is there a way to tell which threads are running in my process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Every once in a while one frame of my game takes too long, I think the reason might be that some thread takes to long to come back. (Just a hint).

I explicitly create only one thread in my game, during loading screen, which is suspended right after. I know that my sound lib also creates one. But I don't know if any other threads are being created. I've used gDebugger to debug thread, and it tells me a lot of threads were initiated but I can't get any info out of it. I want to make sure none of these thread are messing up my game time.

How do I do that? Is there a way to breakpoint at a thread creation in VisualStudio and get the module that did it? I'm using Express edition, but I could get a pro trial only to check that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you break in VS, it will give you a list of currently active threads and their current call stacks.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find it because my current setting had it disabled by default. To enable it I had to go to "Debug -> Windows -> Thread" while running the game. It works on VS2010 Express edition despite MSDN website telling it doesn't.